# puppeteer launch without new page()? new page result secureConnectionStart to be 0

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      args: ['--incognito', '--aggressive-cache-discard'],
      headless: false
});
const context = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();
const page = await context.newPage();
```

Hi there,

When the above code runs, two browsers session will be created, see screenshoot below.

[image]

I was wondering if it's possible not to create new page() and use the first one which was browser was launched?

because the second browser which will always returns me 0 for `secureConnectionStart` when i called `window.performance.timing` for some odd reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure you need `createIncognitoBrowserContext()` if you already launch in incognito. Does this suffice?

```js
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function main() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, args: ['--incognito'] });
    const [page] = await browser.pages();

    await page.goto('https://example.org/');

    // await browser.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Comment: Thank you @vsemozhetbyt